# How to get data from .plist and show it in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In **viewDidLoad** method

```
   array=[NSMutableArray array];
   dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"12.00",@"Tomato"];
   [array addObject:dict];

   dict1=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"75.00",@"Cauliflower"];
   [array addObject:dict1];
```

the problem is I have no idea how to return it for my table view

[image]

**note**: I'm using objective-c

Comment: You say you need help getting data from a plist, but the sample code you posted creates a dictionary literal. Are you saying you need help loading your array from a file instead of from code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an implementation of this:

**Swift 3.1**

```
class whatever {
        let plistsource:String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "plist_name_here", ofType: "plist")!
        var plistData:NSMutableArray?
   ...
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            plistData = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: plistSource)
        }
   ... 
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      ...
        cell.some_lable.text = (plistData!.object(at: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row) as AnyObject).object(forKey: "plist_key") as? String
       // this is all old code, can probably be cleaned up
      ...
        }
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
@interface myClass : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate> {
...
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *plistData;
...
@end

@implementation myClass
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *plistSource = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"plist_name_here" ofType:@"plist"];
    plistDataData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...
    cell.some_label.text = [[[plistData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"plist_key"];
    ...
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get data like this.

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *arrData;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Values" ofType:@"plist"]];
arrData = [dictionary objectForKey:@"KeyName"];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
return cell;
}
```